# Use dynamic parameters for RavenDB query

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I am trying to simplify and compact my code, and eliminate code duplication as much as possible. I have a method that queries RavenDB collections, and the query needs to adapt to the type I am going to query. This type changes according to the parameters passed to the method, and the where clause also needs to adapt.
I have a base type, AdministrativeArea, which other types derive from (Level1_AdministrativeAreas to Level5_AdministrativeAreas). Depending on the scenario, I need to query AdministrativeAreas, Level1_AdministrativeAreas, etc.

What I currently have:

```
    private void Merge(MergeLevel currentMergeLevel, IDocumentSession currentSession)
    {
    (...)
IQueryable<AdministrativeArea> query;
    if (currentMergeLevel == MergeLevel.Level1)
       query = currentSession.Query<AdministrativeArea, AdminAreaName>()
      .Where(area => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(area.NAME_0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(area.NAME_1));
    (...)
    }
```

Is there any way to pass in the types as a method parameter and have them applied to the query, like this:

```
private void Merge(MergeLevel currentMergeLevel, IDocumentSession currentSession, Type requiredType, Type indexType)
    {
        (...)
    IQueryable<requiredType> query;
        if (currentMergeLevel == MergeLevel.Level1)
           query = currentSession.Query<requiredType, indexType>()
          .Where(area => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(area.NAME_0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(area.NAME_1));
        (...)
        }
```

I have faced several problems at compile time, namely "is a variable but is used like a type", and the fact that member variables (NAME_0, NAME_1, etc.) can't be inferred because the compiler doesn't know "what's coming".
I suspect this simply can't be done; however, this has implications for code maintenance, as I'll have to create different methods for each type of query OR create one rather large method. Neither of which are too appealing, but I don't see any way around that.

Comment: It's not very clear, but try with generics: void Merge<RequiredType, IndexType>(int currentMergeLevel, IDocumentSession currentSession)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way of filtering by type would be to include *Raven-Entity-Name* field in the "select" clause of an index.
Then you would be able to filter types by using EntityType field.
You can see an example of this kind of index in the built-in *Raven/DocumentsByEntityName* index

So, your index might look like this:

```
from doc in docs
let entityType = doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"]
where entityType.EndsWith("_AdministrativeAreas")
select new 
{ 
    EntityType = entityType, 
    //the rest of the fields
}
```

*Note that this would work if you are inserting documents through existing client API (raw REST API won't add Raven-Entity-Name on it's own)*

Comment: Michael, that's an interesting approach - I hadn't thought of that ! I ended up familiarising myself with generics, and it turns out to provide a solution for my problem. I will play around with your suggested approach, though. Thank you !